# Git - rm: unrecognized option `--cached'

Tags: git, caching, github, rm

I added `dist` to my `.gitignore` but it was added to the tree in some other way.
I'm trying to remove it and clean up the tree using:

```
rm dist --cached
```

But am getting the error:

```
rm: unrecognized option `--cached'
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try `git rm -r --cached dist`

Comment: In case the previous comment isn't clear, `rm` and `git rm` are different commands.

Comment: `rm` is the Unix command to delete a file, not related in any way to Git. It also works on macOS (because it is also based on Unix) but not on Windows unless you use Git for Windows (aka Git Bash). [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) is the Git command to untrack (and also remove it from the file system unless `--cached` is provided in the command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `rm dist --cached` will not work because the `rm` command does not have the `--cached` option.

> **`rm` documentation**: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/urm.htm
>
> The `rm` command is one of the basic Unix commands.

---

The `--cached` flag is one of the options of the `git rm` command. Hence, you can run: `git rm -r --cached dist` to unstage and remove the `dist` folder from the index.

> **`git rm` documentation:** https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm
>
> `--cached` 
>   Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index.
>   Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.
>
> `-r`
>   Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.

The following thread might give you more information as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/5237070